# searching for the integral of $(x^2-1)y' = xy$

Tags: integration

I've been stuck on a problem for a little while now, and would like some help with it. 
I need to do the integral of $$(x^2 -1)y' = xy$$
i know that i need to put the ys together and the xs together, so i get:
$$x/(x^2 - 1) = y'/y$$
but then im stuck... i know the $\frac{y’}{y}$ will give $ln(|y|)$ but for the xs, i've tried replacing $x^2-1$ by $u$ and then integrate, but i dont get the answer im supposed to get which is:

$y^2 = a(x^2-1)$ where a is a constant

if you could help i'd be very grateful!

Sophie

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format maths.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2-1) \frac{dy}{dx} = xy \\
\int \frac{dy} {y} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2x}{x^2-1} dx \\
\ln y =\frac{1}{2} (\ln (x^2-1 ) +\ln a ) \\
y^2 = a(x^2-1).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{x}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\log |x^2-1|+c_1 = \log\sqrt{|x^2-1|}+c_1, c_1 \in \mathbb{R}.$$
On the other side
$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \log|y|+c_2, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}. $$
So
$$\log|y| = \log\sqrt{|x^2-1|}+C, C \in \mathbb{R}$$
which, taking the exponentials, gives
$$|y| = \sqrt{|x^2-1|}e^C$$
and taking the squares
$$y^2 = a|x^2-1|, a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}.$$